# Raspberry PI 4 + Huawei E3372 - Send AT commands

Tags: raspberry-pi, at-command, usb-modeswitch

I'm trying to send AT commands to a Huawei E3372 USB Dongle but I haven't figured out how to mount correctly.

If I do lsusb, I get the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:034a HP, Inc Elite Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The dongle is listed, I can also access it's configuration screen on 192.168.1.1 and I can access internet.

I have tried creating the config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:14db
```

and entered the following configuration

```
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProduct=0x14db

MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NoDriverLoading=1
```

I have tried various configurations found on the web but none seems to work.

```
/dev/tty    /dev/tty19  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty40  /dev/tty51  /dev/tty62
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty2   /dev/tty30  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty52  /dev/tty63
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty20  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty53  /dev/tty7
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty21  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty54  /dev/tty8
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty22  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty55  /dev/tty9
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty23  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty45  /dev/tty56  /dev/ttyAMA0
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty24  /dev/tty35  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty57  /dev/ttyprintk
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty25  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty58
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty59
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty6
/dev/tty17  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty60
/dev/tty18  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty50  /dev/tty61
```

No more luck with dmesg | grep ttyUSB that returns nothing (same for USB0, USB1,...)

It's probably something wrong in the config file but I don't see exactly what needs to be done.

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem with the E3372h-320 USB GMS dongle.  Did  you every get this figured out?...

Comment: @RDK not through AT Commands actually. The dongle has an API that you can query from your browser so I built a PHP scripts that loads that page and scrape the content.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I really want to proceed with AT commands, but will investigate the API.  Do you have any experience with using the API with Python?

Comment: No but it's not going to be a challenge for Python. There is a url you need to access, something liek 192.168.x.x depending on which device you are using and you then need to add a call like /signal/ (depends on your device too), it will return structured data in return (in my case it was XML). You then need to parse the output. I have created a cron tasks in PHP that calls this API every minute and I then parse the result locally.

Comment: BTW read more about this here: https://github.com/pixelspark/tymodem
Seems like there are two versions of the USB stick - the difference is only the firmware. Means you can reflash your usb stick with other firmware to get AT commands via serial communication.

Comment: More on this topic: https://www.0xf8.org/2017/01/flashing-a-huawei-e3372h-4g-lte-stick-from-hilink-to-stick-mode/ how to reflash it from H to S.

Answer (score 1):

You attach wrong **lsusb** output. The dongle is not listed.

Perhaps the device code **14db** and accessible 192.168.1.1 looks like your modem is switched to newest mode where the dongle looks like router. If you would like to send AT command then you must change mode to serial. First of all try it through:

```
/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
```

The last part of the file contain your desired option:

```
HuaweiAltModeGlobal=0
```

Notice the comment above this option:

> ...you can globally set an alternative method here which provides a
> different mode:  either plain serial PPP...

Just try to change number. There should be around 6 modes and one of them will switch your dongle to serial mode.

Best luck.

Comment: I have a similar problem with the e3372h-320 USB GSM dongle.  When I look at the /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf file i do not see either the comment nor the HuaweiAltModeGlobal=0.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have  you solved that @RDK?